exchange order of limit of random variable
Suppose to have a sequence of discrete random variables $X_n(\lambda)$ depending on some parameter $\lambda \ \in [0,\infty]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that the following limits hold almost surely:

$X_n(\lambda) \rightarrow X(\lambda)$ for $ n \rightarrow \infty$

$X_n(\lambda) \rightarrow X_n$ for $ \lambda \rightarrow \infty$

$X_n \rightarrow X^*$ for $ n \rightarrow \infty$

$X(\lambda) \rightarrow X$ for $ \lambda \rightarrow \infty$


I cannot find in the literature if there are sufficient conditions under which the random variables $X$ and $X^{*}$ are equal in some sense (ex, equal in distributions, almost surely, in probability, etc....). Do you know if there are some interesting results about it? Thank you very much for the help.

Hi: I think your $\lambda$ should be $\lambda_n$ since it's a sequence.

A deterministic example to show what can go wrong is $$X_n(t) = \left(\frac{t}{t+1}\right)^n \quad \forall t \in [0, \infty), n \in {1, 2, 3, ...}$$

To ensure $P[X=X^*]=1$, you want some type of uniform convergence, such as defining $Y(t)=\sup_n|X_n(t)-X_n|$ and assuming $Y(t)\rightarrow 0$ in probability as $t\rightarrow\infty$. Then, I think you can replace all your four bullets with the weaker "convergence in probability" assumption.

Thank you very much, uniform convergence in probability is a very good point. Do you think one ca use a sort of Weierstrass test for random variables? like if $\vert X_n(t)\vert < M_n $ constant in t, then if  the series of $M_n$ is convergent i have uniform convergence in t of $X_n(t)$ (in probabilty)?
